# How can I check if there is a Specific Word in a fileline?

Tags: file, python-3.10, linecache

How can i fix my problem? I want to check if there is a specific word in a Textfile line and then run some code. Can someone please help me? Thanks alot.

```
    if key == Key.left:
        mouse.move(901, 350, absolute=True, duration=0.02)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        mouse.click("left")
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        f = open('Get Position.txt', 'a+')
        f.write('LEFT \n')

    if key == Key.enter:
        file = open('Get Position.txt', 'r')
        file.close() 

with open('Get Position.txt') as file:                            
            contents = file.read()
            search_word = linecache.getline('Get Position.txt', 1)
            if search_word in contents == 'LEFT \n':
                print('LEFT WAS PRESSED')
                mouse.move(901, 350, absolute=True, duration=0.02)
                time.sleep(0.0001)
                mouse.click("left")
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are attempting to do with `if search_word in contents == 'LEFT \n':`?  I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: i want to see if the search word so the first line in the text file is 'LEFT' but i dont know how linecache registers that word

Comment: `search_word` is the line from the file, and `contents` is the whole file, so why do you need to check if `search_word` is in `contents`?

Comment: so it would work if i just delete that contest thing right ?

Comment: Not knowing what is in the file, I couldn't say, but seems worth a try.